# Validation control ASP.NET internet explorer issue?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, sharepoint

I have the following validation controls:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="GebeurtenisTekstRequiredValidator" ControlToValidate="GebeurtenisTekst" Display="Dynamic" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Er is geen gebeurtenis.<br />" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="GebeurtenisTekstMaxLength" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="GebeurtenisTekst" ValidationExpression="^[\s\S]{1,500}$" errormessage="- Maximaal 500 karakters.<br />" />
```

The validation control:

```
<SharePoint:InputFormTextBox RichText="false" ID="GebeurtenisTekst" runat="server" Rows="4" Columns="60" MaxLength="500" TextMode="MultiLine"></SharePoint:InputFormTextBox>
```

In Internet Explorer (9) i don't get a message when i paste more then 500 characters. In chrome I receive the validationmessage: "Maximaal 500 karakters". Is this a IE issue and how can i fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is an Ie 9 issue, i've been in the same situation, it seems ie9 does not have all the data-val-* html 5 tags implemented, that's why in other browsers its possible. Rest assured your coding is correct.

Comment: not really, just with an upgrade to IE or in IE 10. its the way ie sees the document itself. thats all there is to it.

Comment: yes there is, javascript, and a function specifically that solves your problem, tahts how i got around the problem. On the submit event check if the character length is larger then 500 chars, if so, add c class to your element colouring it with red, if the length is below 500 remove the red coloured class. You can use jquery for that also.

Comment: also be sure if the lenghts exceeds 500 chars to return false as well so your form will not submit. and if its correct return true, thats the way the browser DOM works.  Something like this: $("form").on("submit", function (e) {
            
            if ($("#box2View option").length > 500) {
                $("#box2View").addClass("input-validation-error");